# How to avoid regression to the mean in a simple comparison

Tags: regression, anova, contrasts, psychology

This is a pretty simple question but I haven't been able to find a clear answer to it. I have some data from a behavioral experiment taken under two conditions (A and B); within each condition, each trial could have one of two outcomes (correct or error). Moreover I repeated the experiment on many subjects.

If I consider only correct trials, I know that for some subjects the response is significantly higher during A than it is during B, and for other subjects the effect is reversed. This effect is quite strong for individual subjects and I'm convinced it's real; it's just that the direction can go either way.

I'm interested in making a statement like: the response on correct trials is significantly different across conditions A and B, but this effect is diminished (or absent, or reversed) for error trials. This could be either a statement about each individual subject, or the population.

The problem is this: once I specify whether A or B is greater for each subject based on the correct trials, I am pretty sure that the effect will tend to be less on the error trials simply because of regression to the mean. That is, even if correct trials and error trials are actually identical, if I select the direction of the effect based on the correct trials, it will tend to be less on the error trials.

First I am interested to hear if you think this is a real thing to worry about. Secondly I am interested in what I should do about it.

This feels like a "planned contrast" problem to me although I've never done this. I think it would be something like abs(A_hit - B_hit) > abs(A_error - B_error). One problem is that I usually like to use Mann-Whitney U-test for my data because it isn't very normal, but if the only tools for this problem rely on normality assumption I'm willing to let it slide.

Comment: I don't completely understand. So you have a within-subjects design, every subject experiences both conditions, is that correct? And then you repeat the experiment so that you have multiple experiments with within-subjects design?

Comment: Yes, every subject experiences both conditions A and B. Also, every subject makes both correct and error trials. Considering only correct trials, the dependent variable (brain response) is higher on condition A for some subjects, and higher on condition B for other subjects. The question is how to analyze whether the strength of the dependent variable differs on error trials than on correct trials.